# Ansible remote_user: root, ssh: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to change the password using playbook but not getting the permission to do so.

I'm running the command:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -k
```

---

```
- hosts: servers
  remote_user: root
  vars:
   password: $1$Izd9zEZS$T11sNBK3bQgbzWkBMZq.
  tasks:
   - name: Changing Passwords
     user:
      name=root
      password={{password}}
```

> fatal: [host1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to
>   connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).",
>   "unreachable": true}

Comment: Please format your question more properly https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It seems that Ansible has some issues with connection to the host1. Verbose output (`-vvvv`) should provide more info about which step is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share the key to hot machine using below commands.

Save the .pub key :

`ssh-keygen`

Copy the key to host machine using ssh-copy-id command.

```
ssh-copy-id <IP address>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

> fatal: [host1]:..."msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey)."

The error message says that *`ansible_user`*, i.e the user who is running the command ansible-playbook, or *`ansible_user`* set in the inventory of the group *`servers`*, is not able to connect via SSH to *`root@host1`* (see *`remote_user: root`* in the playbook), because the public key of *`ansible_user`* is missing in *`authorized_keys`* of *`root@host1`*.

**Solution**

To fix this problem, put the public key of *`ansible_user`* (in most cases *`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`*) into the *`authorized_keys`* of *`root@host1`* (in most cases *`/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`*).

**Best practice**

The best practice is not to allow root to login via SSH. Secure systems disable root login via SSH by default.

```
$ grep PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin no
```

Instead, best practice is to SSH as an unprivileged user, e.g. *`remote_user: admin`* and escalate the privilege *`become: yes`*. See details in [Understanding Privilege Escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#understanding-privilege-escalation).

Answer (score 0):

Put the username and password in 'etc\ansible\hosts'

*[server]
172.30.141.1 ansible_password=xxx ansible_user=root*

and test the connectivity by executing the following command

*ansible all -m ping*

it works for me.